# Double integration with bounded by three lines

Tags: integration

$\int\int(x^2-xy-1)\,dx\,dy$, over $D$ is the triangular region bounded by the lines $x-2y+2=0,x+3y-3=0$ and $y=0$[image] I have tried to integrate this by type -2 (horizontal type region ) and able to get the correct answer.Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Set $x-2y+2=x+3y-3=0$. Solving, we have $y=1$. We also know the figure is bounded by $y=0$. Then you may set up your integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{2y-2}^{-3y+3}x^{2}-xy-1\,dx\,dy$. Now just evaluate.

Comment: Those bounds are a rectangle.  $D$ is a triangle.

Comment: fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see that your integral has $dx \; dy$ rather than $dy \; dx$.  The limits for $y$ are $0$ to $1$.  The $x$ limits are found by solving the two equations for $x$.